# What secret/unused weapons are in Half-Life 2?

Tags: half-life-2

I was playing around with some stuff in Hammer Editor one day, when I found a weapon that piqued my interest:
`weapon_alyxgun`
Sure enough, it was Alyx's gun. The viewmodel had no hands, and was a giant gun jutting out of the screen, but it still worked just like Alyx's gun.
Later, I found another weapon - `weapon_cubemap`. It was six shiny spheres in front of the screen.
I was wondering what other weapons might be unlocked through the `give` command. Are there any others that occur in vanilla Half-Life 2, not any betas or mods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following list [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_HL2_entities).

> weapon_357 - The 357
>
> weapon_alyxgun - Alyx's gun. It was not supposed to be used by the player so it lacks a viewmodel
>
> weapon_annabelle - Grigori's shotgun. It was not supposed to be used by the player so it lacks a viewmodel. It takes two 357 rounds for each shot
>
> weapon_ar2 - The pulse rifle
>
> weapon_brickbat - An unfinished and unreleased gun. It is unusable as it lacks models
>
> weapon_bugbait - Bugbait
>
> weapon_crossbow - The crossbow
>
> weapon_crowbar - The crowbar
>
> weapon_frag - The frag grenade
>
> weapon_physcannon - The gravity gun
>
> weapon_pistol - The pistol
>
> weapon_rpg - The RPG
>
> weapon_shotgun - The shotgun
>
> weapon_smg1 - The smg
>
> weapon_striderbuster - The strider buster
>
> weapon_stunstick - The Combine stunstick

*Descriptions added by me*

This means that `weapon_alyxgun` and `weapon_annabelle` are the only weapons that can only be acquired with the `give` command.

Comment: Side question - could I give the brickbat, stunstick, etc. custom models to make it work?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI You could add custom models to any of these, it is the same way for any Source game.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this one:

> weapon_citizensuitcase

It's a suit case used by a male citizen at the beginning of the game.

Keep in mind that the viewmodel will take up 2/3 of your screen if you use it.